# Initialize db before running Spring boot REST controller end-to-end test

Tags: java, spring

I use JPA/Hibernate for my Spring boot app. I'm writing ftests for the REST controllers.

I want to alter the db state (insert some rows, etc) and test the REST controller to see if it returns/works as expected.

It doesn't sound right to use the Service layer to initialize the database (at the end that's what we want to test as it's an end-to-end test!).

What is the best way to initialize database in a test for Spring boot app?

**Note**
I've heard of [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) but it uses xml, and I'd rather use java code.

Answer (score 4):

I know of three options here

**1. import.sql in Hibernate**

It's as simple as adding an import.sql to your src/test/resources folder. Inside import.sql you can type in your sql to insert data you want. You would also have to set hibernate-ddl-auto to create in application.properties.

eg. Application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/asgard
spring.datasource.username=thor
spring.datasource.password=mjolnir
```

eg import.sql

```
insert into 
    account  (id, createddate, modifieddate, password , username, disabled) 
    values (-1, now(),null, 'password','admin',false);
```

---

**2. Spring Test DB Unit**

[Spring Test DB Unit](https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) is DB Unit specifically for Spring. This basically lets you add data and remove it after test on method as well as class level which is very useful. Check the link for more details. The xml actually makes it easier to manage the data you want to insert. You can also insert data programatically but it's more complicated and instructions should be there on the website.

---

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup(value = "insert.xml")
@DatabaseSetup(connection="customerDataSource", value="insert-custs.xml")
public void testInsert() throws Exception {
    // Inserts "insert.xml" into dataSource and "insert-custs.xml" into customerDataSource
    // ...
}
```

---

eg insert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <Person id="0" title="Mr" firstName="Phillip" lastName="Webb"/>
</dataset>
```

Table name is person along with id,title,firstName and lastName as fields.

**3. Using @Before annotation**

Using @Before annotation in Test class to set up db.

GenericTest Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GenericTest {

    public EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        employeeRepository.save(createRandomEmployeeObject());
    }

    @Test
    public void insertSuccess(){
        List<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findAll();

        //Logic to get employee from rest API

        //Assert if data from rest API matches one in db

    }
}
```

Comment: it is still using `sql`, not java, which is not very different from `xml` from my point of view. 
I want to be able to compare the actual values with expected values (those inserted in to the db, which lives in the `sql` file). Therefore I prefer to alter the db with java code, not `xml` or `sql`

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh the xml is for intitial data set up, you just use controllers/service layer in the tests

Comment: I know, but in assertions, I compare what was inserted into the db with what is returned by the REST controller. right ? the inserted values in the db, are actually in the sql file.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I have added a 3rd option of using `@Before ` annotation on test class. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user2049132 That was what I thought about too. But there's a problem here. Sometimes, calling repository from a class not annotated with `@Transactional` causes some issues. Does it make sense to annotate a test class with `@Transactional` ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh You can call repository from a class not annotated with `@Transactional`. Maybe you have a specific case... what issue do you get?

Comment: I get this error when I want to access an object which is in `OneToMany` relation with another object (through a `getter` method): `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role`. One way to resolve this issue without changing the fetch type is to access it inside a class annotated with `@Transactional`

Comment: I have a similar setup, but i'm not testing the rest api results against the db, but i insert data to the db and verify that the data inserted is correct. I also have an object with `OneToMany` relation with lazy loading and it works perfectly fine without the need for @Transactional. I'm using SpringDataRepositories for DAL. For that purpose, i do something like this..... `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class JpaRepositoryTest` maybe this will work?